# How to install gatsby in AWS lambda?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, gatsby

I want to create gatsbyjs site using aws lambda ?
Any one have idea how we can install gatby nmp package globally in AWS lambda ?
I want to execute

```
npm install -g gatsby
```

How can I execut this in aws lambda?

Comment: Why do u need it globally, could u specify that?

Comment: actully I want to create gatsby site using aws lamda. I want to execute gatsby new gatsby-site this command using lambda function. If you know anyother way to do please help me for that

Comment: Did you ever get this to run?

Answer (score 1):

You can just install the necessary dependencies directly. Gatsby is just NPM packages like any other node.js project.

Answer (score 0):

We've recently had a similar requirement, and the answer is [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/). Lambda's have a 250mb ceiling, and Gatsby is much larger than this (~500mb).

By installing Gatsby in your EFS instance, and mounting that instance to your Lambda, you'll be building pages in no time.

There's a few other caveats however; I put together an overview of how to do it here:
https://www.jameshill.dev/articles/running-gatsby-within-aws-lambda/